# Invalid Network Credentials in Admob mediation process

Tags: ios, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation, facebook-monetization-manager

Entering Facebook App id and Access token throwing Invalid network credentials.
For mediation I followed this Integration link https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/facebook.

As one of the steps, I don't find any apps to select in the list. Attaching the screenshot as shown in integration steps.

I only doubt for Invalid network credentials by missing this step in my flow.
[image: I don't find apps in this list]

Comment: I don't know what happened but after few days when I open Admob and go into mediation and clicked on the Add Facebook Audience Manager they didn't ask me for network credentials. They just asked for Placement ID and my job done. I think because of I had already inserted credentials on my first app mediation and they were asking me again by mistake and I was getting error. So it is now mediating. cheers!

Answer (score 8):

nowadays Admob asks for property id. from Facebook you only get a placement id. in that placement id use the text before underscore as property id in google Admob.

for example, if  `123456789101112_13141516171819` is your placement id, `123456789101112` should be your property id